# Changing CSS of single form element

Tags: html, css, forms

As you can see, there is a search form on the left sidebar of [this](http://cizgiaydinlatma.com/) web site.

I want to change "only" that forms background to white, and make it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsmPb.png).

What code shall i add to custom css section?

All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem, how to refer to that element or the css to change the background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following css:

```
.search.showtextback {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer only changed the search form as i wanted. Rest of the answer was changing all the forms around website. Thank you again!

Comment: @Burcak you welcome and glad to help. Don't forget to mark/accept it as answer by clicking right symbol. And from next time, please post sample code in your question.

Comment: i did, thanks. what do you mean by sample code?

Comment: @Burcak sample code means. html and css which you are using and have issue. like here in your question. html of left sidebar and css which left sidebar you are using. But, no worry about it now.

Answer (score 0):

Add background to focus

```
input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus{background:#fff;}
```

remove this background for this class

```
   .select2-container .select2-choice, input[type="date"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="email"], input[type="input"], input[type="month"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="text"], input[type="time"], input[type="url"], select, textarea
{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02); /* Remove this background*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your css

```
input[type="text"] {
 background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input.search.showtextback {
    background: #fff !important;
}
```